# Выбор случайных элементов из массива

Tags: c#

Код ниже по идее должен 20 раз выбрать случайное число из массива, но получается почему-то 20 раз подряд одно и то же число.

```
int[] mas = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
int count = 0;
do
{
Random rnd = new Random();
int nm = mas[rnd.Next(0, 8)];
Console.WriteLine(nm);
count++;
}
while (count < 20);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Классическая ошибка по работе с `Random`: нельзя в цикле каждый раз создавать новый экземпляр переменной типа `Random`. Вынесите перед циклом создание этой переменной, а в цикле уже используйте ее.

Answer (score 1):

У вас объекты класса `Random` создаются с одинаковым сидом, поэтому и метод `Next()` будет возвращать одни и те же цифры. Создайте один экземпляр `Random`, а в цикле вызывайте метод `Next()`.

Если вы используете счётчик для цикла и в теле цикла нет условий для этого счётчика, то лучше использовать цикл `for` вместо `do while`.

```
int[] mas = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
Random rnd = new Random();
for (int count = 0; count < 20; count++)
{
    int nm = mas[rnd.Next(0, 8)];
    Console.Write(nm + " ");
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]